# Android Eclipse project using the Graphical Layout can't add TextView or MultiLineView

Tags: android, eclipse, ide

I've looked at several other questions related, one answer even seemed like it solved the problem however I was wrong.

The issue is I get:

```
Parser exception for C:\Documents and Settings\djordan\My Documents\SampleTest\AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
```

When I drag/drop a new TextView or Multiline Text view item to the canvas.  All other Text Fields add fine.

EDIT: Pasted the wrong error ... updated. and Added following work flow:
1. open SDK, check API 16 installed.
2. open Eclipse, create new Android project
   - name, target/minimum API 16
3. in Graphical Layout drag "Plain Text" or "MultiLine Text" from the Text Fields.
4. view error above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flip over to the xml page, go through and find the textView you just added. Find the attribute where it says android:textSize="18" and change it to android:textSize="18dip" That should solve it. The error is telling you that the units for that attribute are not valid or were not set.

Comment: please see the edit I made ... sorry about that - pasted the wrong line from the error log.

Comment: android:minSdkVersion="16"
android:targetSdkVersion="15" <-- that's likely your problem. minSdkVersion limits what devices can run your app. Saying you're targeting devices that run versions of android below your minimum sdk version will probably create problems. Try making the target version 16 or making the min version at least 15 and see if that helps. Also, please tell me that relative layout is from a different file and you just pasted it in as a second reference and not part of the manifest.

Comment: First I tried editing the Manifest to change the Min API to 16 ... then I created a new project with the Min API 16.  Both had the same problem as the original.

Comment: As for the RelativeLayout - the title of the pastebin might not have been too clear, I included both the Activity XML and the Manifest XMl ...  they are different files, yes.

Comment: What have you tried? I can't seem to replicate the error you are getting, but I got the same error as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275754/exception-in-loading-layout-java-util-linkedhashmap-eldestljava-util-mapentr) and they have found a solution. Perhaps you are getting a similar error and it's simply displaying a bit differently.

Comment: okay.  That seems to help.  I had to create a new project, simply modifingy the manifest file wasn't sufficient.  But at least I can understand what the problem is, and how to correct it, even if not the existing project.  Thanks for the link.