# .xml layout file not working because of <EditText> body

Tags: android, xml, file, layout

I'm working on an very simple example i found on the internet , but my main.xml layout file isn't working.

When i add the  body in main.xml , it can't display a thing.

Any help is appreciated :)

Here's the main.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
<EditText android:id="@+id/myEditText" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/new_to_do_item" android:hint="@string/hint_msg" /> 
<ListView android:id="@+id/myListView" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: By the way , someone should improve the way someone posts a question..

Its so ugly and so misleading , the way the comments are posted!

Comment: Hi, dont blame SO for this, I have just copied your file content easily, so please remove your comment with the code

Comment: Use the code markup button or the keyboard shortcut (`Ctrl+K`) to add code. Press the `?` button on the top right of the editor window to read formatting help. Don't blame Stack Overflow on your inability to use it.

Comment: 1. when i was posting the comment , it didnt display the contents of the .xml file on the preview display screen.. probably some loading problems.

2. Could someone help me how to post a code part correctly ?? 
I tried (Ctrl+K) but it doesnt help that much ... In fact , i was trying to post this comment for about 5'...

Answer (score 1):

Use `<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

**instead of**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";
```

**Try this...**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/myEditText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/hint_msg"
        android:text="@string/new_to_do_item" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thats exactly my .xml file , samir .. 
But when i posted this question , it dissapeared .. Sorry but the code markup button isnt so helpful to me.. 
So , any other help would be appreciated :)

Comment: When i delete the <EditText> body , it works just fine... thats a hint :P

Comment: Ok , found the real cause of the problem 
wrong Target API and a lot of nerves ( for some other reasons ) blurred me :)

Sorry for wasting your time :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; 
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
```

to

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
```

works for me

Edit:
to slow^^

Edit2:

To add something usefull: You have to tag XML or HTML markups as "Codesample", then they show up normally

Edit3:

[Exception in loading layout: java.util.LinkedHashMap.eldest()Ljava/util/Map$Entry;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275754/exception-in-loading-layout-java-util-linkedhashmap-eldestljava-util-mapentr)

the first answer seems to have worked for some people

Comment: thnx mate ;) ill give it a try ;)

Comment: it's exactly what Samir Mangroliya wrote ;)

Comment: But .. i have the exact same file with Samir .. and doesnt work for me...

When i turn to the Graphic Layout window , it says :

java.util.LinkedHashMap.eldest()Ljava/util/Map$Entry;

Comment: i edited a link into my answer, maybe try the solution presented there

Comment: Yeah , that was the problem. Solved it some minutes. U take your vote up , though ;)