# Android XML error while adding EditText on console

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I am trying to make an xml in which there is some buttons and also some edittext with textviews. but when i try to add a edittext of multiline it get save it is start showing errors like "java.util.LinkedHashMap.eldest()Ljava/util/Map$Entry;"
 my XML code is:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/to"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/to"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/toname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/to"
        android:layout_below="@+id/to"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/toname"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tophone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/toname"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toname"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:hint="@string/tophone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="phone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/importbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tophone"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tophone"
        android:text="@string/importbutton" />



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/to"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/importbutton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/importbutton"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/text"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="7"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/text"
        android:text="@string/sendbutton" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

plz help how to make this...

Answer (score 0):

You should check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275754/exception-in-loading-layout-java-util-linkedhashmap-eldestljava-util-mapentr)
Also try doing

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Comment: thnx ,it is working but i m getting only one line and i want to show 7 lines in this edittext as it is a multiline text...

Comment: Actually your designed layout is working fine in my system. I am not getting on which point you are getting the error. Can you highlight that point?

Comment: Can you accept the answer if it helped you. Else share your answer So that it helps the community