# autocompletetextview changes view color and disable whole view?

Tags: android, android-view, textview

Well I am new to android design

My graphical view is this

http://cubixshade.com/test/before.jpg

BUt when I drop autocompletetextview field on the view in the eclipse, it shows this

http://cubixshade.com/test/after.jpg

My whole screen gets wired and disabled and can not put more autocompletetextview. what is happening ?

Comment: try cleaning your project or perhaps give a restart to your eclipse :)

Comment: when i put field  it gives me this message in error log  create_beachon.xml: java.util.LinkedHashMap.eldest()Ljava/util/Map

Comment: cleaning and restarting does not work. eclipse sucks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having the same problem (very new to Android here, so bear with me). I see in the StackTrace it says the error comes from ...SpellChecker. So I thought maybe if I disable spell checking on my edit field, that I could work around the error until the update to the eclipse tool.

following the instructions here: Android Ice Cream Sandwich Edittext: Disabling Spell Check and Word Wrap I added

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

This solved the problem for me.

Comment: and the link is  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275754/exception-in-loading-layout-java-util-linkedhashmap-eldestljava-util-mapentr